# Ocaml longest substring

Tags: string, module, char, substring, ocaml

I have a problem with some exercise. 
I've to find the longest substring.

*Example:*

```
"AGATGCCATTGTCCCCGACAACCAGCCA"
```

Which I have to transform into List and find/search for longest substring and print the result `CCCC`

My function must be like that `function search : char list -> unit`

And I cant use *Module Str*.

Comment: The longest substring of `AGATGCCATTGTCCCCGACAACCAGCCA` is `AGATGCCATTGTCCCCGACAACCAGCCA`.

Comment: What ideas do you have for solving the problem? Have you written any (pseudo-) code to solve it? If so, show it to us and explain why you think it doesn't work. Clearly you don't want SO commenters to just answer your homework for you, right?

Comment: Hehe, right, no, Iam still trying myself but I'm stuck. I've some ideas, but I don't know how realized it. I am thinking to use "match with" function and some variables to save current longest number and string. But then I am not able to count it or what I've to do If i found some longer substring, how to reset the previous one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answer is appropriate. I believe I should give a hint.

Recall the iterative algorithm for finding the maximum number in an array.

```
int maximum = array[0];
for (i = 1; i < length; i++){
    if (array[i] > maximum){
        maximum = array[i];
    }
}
```

To translate the code into a recursive one, we do not mutate values as we go along, but have a different parameter in the next call.

```
let max_in_list =
let rec aux maximum l = match l with
    |[] -> maximum
    |x :: xs -> aux (max maximum x) xs in
function
    |[] -> invalid_arg "empty list"
    |x :: xs -> aux x xs
```

Notice how the `maximum` variable is "changed" in every recursive call, just like the mutated variable in iterations.
Of course this is not the idiomatic way as the recursion can be done with `List.fold_left`.

If you really do not know how to "think recursively", try to come up with an algorithm with loop first, and "translate" it into recursion.